# Why are some outlets not working in two bedrooms?

Tags: electrical

My room is next to my daughter's, I have 4 outlets, she has 3. None of hers are working. Only 1 of mine is working, but only with extension cord, and only sometimes. The others do not work.

I have had this problem for a while. They were supposed to have be fixed, but never were. I am wondering how I can help my situation, and be safe, for me and my daughter.

Comment: Please proof read, and improve question. Then ensure that all relevant information is present.

Comment: Are they all on the same circuit?

Comment: What country and what is the age of the home/wiring?  Is there a ground (remember that sometimes outlets are liars.)

Answer (score 3):

It is probably broken wire or bad connection at a back stab that feeds the chain of outlets. The problem is at the last working outlet (closest to the breakers usually) or the first non working outlet. Figure out this location and turn the breaker off, pull the outlet look for a loose or broken wire it could be either the black or white,  if back stabs were used into the outlet many times the insulation will be melted back at the bad connection, when found replace the outlet and don't use the back stabs pigtail and or use the screw terminals. I have repaired hundreds of these failures and 98% of the time it is a loose backstab connection in the outlet. If you pull the 2 outlets and don't find anything but the other outlets now work , get 2 new outlets and replace those because this will happen again when a good load like a vacuum is plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably going to have to get an electrician to look into this, but it is possible that there is a DIY fix that you can implement.

1. Start off looking at the breaker panel. Are any breakers tripped? (You are not to unscrew the front of the panel. Just open the hinged door to see the switch handles for the breakers. Modern breakers may not give much indication of being in the tripped state. Locate the breaker to the bedrooms and switch it off and then back on.
2. Get a simple plug-in receptacle tester and plug it into a working receptacle and then into all the ones that are not working. Report the results here. It is possible that both bedrooms are on the same breaker. Each room does not necessarily have its own breaker.
3. The fault may be in one or more receptacles in the bedroom rather than in the panel. What brand of panel do you have? Check the sticker on the inside of the hinged door of the panel.

Comment: I’d go on a GFCI hunt as well.  If fit’s an older house in the USA it would also be wise to check any GFCI (for test and reset) that may have been added to the houses over the years.  Many times it’s an unused outlet that the current owner doesn’t even realize exists.

Comment: I disagree on the need for an electrician. This is usually a very simple outlet replacement that most any home owner can do.

Comment: I'd recommend checking the voltage on all the outlets on the circuit too.